# Unable to scan type of uuid.UUID into UUID in sqlmock Golang

Tags: go, go-sqlmock

I have the following test function.

```
func (s *Suite) Test_delete() {
    var (
        id       = uuid.New()
        name     = "test"
        quantity = 2
    )
    s.mock.ExpectQuery(regexp.QuoteMeta(
        `SELECT * FROM "items" WHERE code = $1 AND "items"."deleted_at" IS NULL`,
    )).
        WithArgs(id).
        WillReturnRows(sqlmock.NewRows([]string{"code", "name", "quantity"}).
            AddRow(id, name, quantity))

    err := s.repository.DeleteItem(id.String())
    require.NoError(s.T(), err)
}
```

Now the problem is trying to scan the `id` variable into the `row` for the column `code`. In my `Product` struct, I have `code` defined as follows.

```
type Item struct {
    Code      uuid.UUID      `gorm:"type:uuid;primaryKey" json:"code"`
    Name      string         `json:"name" validate:"required"`
    Quantity  int            `json:"qty" validate:"required,min=0"`
    DeletedAt gorm.DeletedAt `json:"-" gorm:"index"`
}

func (i *Item) BeforeCreate(tx *gorm.DB) (err error) {
    if i.Code == uuid.Nil {
        i.Code = uuid.New()
    }
    return
}
```

Now the problem is when I try to run the test function, it is somehow unable to scan `uuid.UUID` into `UUID` even though they are both the same types. Here is the exact error message.

```
msql: Scan error on column index 0, name "code": Scan: unable to scan type uuid.UUID into UUID
```

Could someone help me on this part?

Comment: Not an answer, but I was reading uuid code, and it works only with string or []byte types it seems, for other types it will throw your error - https://github.com/google/uuid/blob/master/sql.go#L15

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](https://github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock/blob/44e746a20e094153210b5b25fea30c38804a8b29/rows.go#L166). I assume there is type casting error. Changing `WillReturnRows(sqlmock.NewRows([]string{"code", "name", "quantity"}).AddRow(id, name, quantity))`->`WillReturnRows(sqlmock.NewRows([]string{"code", "name", "quantity"}).AddRow(id.String(), name, quantity))` may help.